# Did we get this full stack webapp architecture right?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am working on a full-stack spring-java based web app. The app is current divided between two projects each of which produce a war file on build. One project (call it UI) serves as the front-end of the app. UI doesn't have much business logic in it. Mostly HTML templates, and JS/CSS and other resources. The other project (call it Server) carries a whole lot of weight in terms of providing auth, business logic, DB services, REST API for external world etc.

I am running into quite a few problems especially while making security work throughout the app given UI project has no direct way to authenticate a user or checking user roles etc. UI relies on invoking a REST OAuth2 password flow to Server to authenticate. So authentication itself works fine but I am having a tough time checking user access roles or any other fine grained permissions within any code in UI project.

Before I dig a whole lot deeper and try to make this all work, a couple of questions for the gurus here:
a) Is this design one of the acceptable ways to build web apps?
b) Are there any gotchas that I should be aware of if I attempt to bundle the two projects within one war?

I hope this is to the point but let me know if you need any more details, and I will be happy to add color.

Comment: Our project uses the same structure and we have not had any problems so far. Separating your business and other logic from your UI is indeed the correct way to go.
Your problem is the lack of interfaces to access "Server" functionality in "UI". For this purpose you could write a custom tag library for use in your templates; or you can separate your page section templates for authenticated and unauthenticated users.
I personally would recommend the tag library approach as most third party security frameworks (as Shiro) do provide tag libraries to query roles and such.

Comment: @Abhishek not sure if a custom tag library can help here. I'd like to use role based authorization in spring configuration using intercept-url but can't do it. Also, method level PreAuthorize don't work either because user sessions are created without authorities. One of my immediate problems is how do I communicate user roles from Server project to UI project when authenticating using OAuth2.

Comment: Can't you just retrieve user's roles from the server and store them in the UI session?

Comment: @UMad user roles are part of the Oauth token but I don't think I can decrypt this token on the UI without having a reference to the same ClientDetails and TokenServices that Server used to create the token in the first place. If I do some sort of DB query to get user roles for the authenticated user, it kinda defeats the purpose of having a separate UI layer.

Answer (score 0):

Try another concept for separation:

- Module 1 = core business logic -> produces **jar** file on build
- Module 2 = web -> produces war file on build

Module 2 depends on module 1. All security stuff goes to module 2.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Maksym.  This sounds logical and reasonable. I will work it out and update here if this works out well for my needs.